# Help with MySQL Query syntax: ERROR #1066 - Not unique table/alias

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-error-1066

I have four tables, `user`, `user_billingprofile`, `user_shippingprofile`, and `user_address`.

**user:** userId, dateCreated
**user_billingprofile:** userId, address
**user_shippingprofile:** userId, address
**user_address:** random address crap

Here is the query I have to get a users billing and shipping profiles in one shot.

```
SELECT * FROM `user`
  JOIN `user_billingprofile`  ON `user`.`userId` = `user_billingprofile`.`userId`
    JOIN `user_address` ON `user_billingprofile`.`currentAddress` = `user_address`.`addressId`
  JOIN `user_shippingprofile` ON `user_shippingprofile`.`currentAddress` = `user_address`.`addressId`
    JOIN `user_address` ON `user_shippingprofile`.`currentAddress` = `user_address`.`addressId`
```

I get the error: `#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'user_address'`.
*Is there a way to take a simple join where a table is accessed twice in the same query, and separate the two results?* Preferably with some kind of table prefix...

I'm a bit lost here.  I know I could do this in two sepparate queries quite easily, but i'd like to learn how to do stuff like this in one shot.

Any help/suggestions/direction is greatly appreciated, thank you!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you post the structure of your tables? Based on your query I'd say you need to consider changing it up a bit.

That said you can fix your current query by adding a table alias like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `user`
  JOIN `user_billingprofile`  ON `user`.`userId` = `user_billingprofile`.`userId`
    JOIN `user_address` AS user_billing_address ON `user_billingprofile`.`currentAddress` = `user_address`.`addressId`
  JOIN `user_shippingprofile` ON `user_shippingprofile`.`currentAddress` = `user_address`.`addressId`
    JOIN `user_address` AS user_shipping_address ON `user_shippingprofile`.`currentAddress` = `user_address`.`addressId`
```

Note the `AS` clause I added. You'll probably need to alias the columns too (instead of `SELECT *` you likely will need `SELECT user_shipping_address.address AS user_shipping_address_value, user_billing_address.address AS user_billing_address_value ...` )

Hope that helps!